# Upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and Intellij shortcuts are not working properly

Tags: shortcut-keys, 20.04, intellij

Ex: when in 18.04 LTS, shortcut Alt + Ctrl + Shift + S ==> used to open project structure. Now it is opening Settings which is Alt + Ctrl + S. In shortcut menu which is located in Settings -> Keymap it is clearly written Alt + Ctrl + Shift + S for project structure.

I reinstalled Intellij, defaulted to factory settings, deleted all configs from home folder. It is just not working properly.

Now I don't use whole lot of shortcuts but I imagine there are more than this particular case. Anyone has had issues like this?

Comment: It's not specific to ubuntu, I have the same problem on macos. I suspect it is because of latest update. I'm on latest webstorm 2020.1.1

Comment: ok, update: turns out I was running karabiner-events which messed up my keymap in webstorm. Check if you are running custom keyboard event-handler, that may be an issue. There is an existing bug in java which results in such behaviour, afaik.

Comment: Recently I received an Ubuntu update and it seems that the problem is solved.